# Алгоритм генератора случайных чисел

Tags: java, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Нужен алгоритм написания генератора случайных чисел на Java. Библиотек не использовать.

Comment: Алгоритмов полно берите и реализуйте

Comment: А вам именно код нужен или достаточно просто способ получения псевдослучайного числа узнать? Если последнее - то можно так: `Math.random()`. Если первое - то почему без библиотек и если таки без них - то почему не взять библиотеку и не скопировать код оной?

Comment: Без библиотек не нашёл ни одного

Comment: А если поищите исходники библиотек то и найдёте то что ищите

Comment: я только учусь, не знаю как код из библиотеки правильно извлечь, там есть связь с другими библиотеками

Comment: @BunnyHope [Линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Comment: А можно так: https://xkcd.com/221/ 

Answer (score 2):

Прямо вот алгоритм-алгоритм, чтобы соответствовал ряду критериев, ни я, ни кто другой вам тут не напишет (или маловероятно, что напишет). Но в качестве отправной точки вот вам случайное число без использования соответствующих библиотек:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
int rand = now.getNano();
        
System.out.println(rand);
```

Суть: берём текущий момент, из него вытаскиваем наносекунды, которые, разумеется, каждый раз будут разными.

Что делать с получившимся числом -- решайте сами. Я бы донакинул ещё энтропии. Плюс есть чисто математические способы, как изначальное зерно (seed, а у вас здесь что-то типа этого зерна) далее сделать как бы более случайным. Но эту тему так просто не раскроешь. Для учебного задания приведённого материала (возможно с небольшой доработкой) вполне достаточно.